# Random Numbers within a Range

Tags: java, for-loop, random

This is a tool that you could use to generate an order for positions in any circumstance.

However, I am encountering infinite loops. How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WhoGoesFirst {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int MIN = 1;
        int students = 0;

        System.out.print("How many students do you have?");
        students = input.nextInt();

        int comp = random.nextInt(students - MIN + 1) + MIN;

        for (int number = 0; number <= students; comp++) {
            System.out.println(random);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never increment `number`.

Answer (score 4):

Increment your number variable in the loop and it should fix the issue:

```
for (int number = 0; number <= students; number++, comp++) {
                System.out.println(comp); //random is an object
        }
```

Comment: Why not just increment comp inside of the loop and number in the for (as it should be)

Comment: Or both... `for(int number=0; number <= students; number++, comp++) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

You need to increment number:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WhoGoesFirst {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int MIN = 1;
        int students = 0;

        System.out.print("How many students do you have?");
        students = input.nextInt();

        int comp = random.nextInt(students - MIN + 1) + MIN;

        for (int number = 0; number <= students; number++) {
                System.out.println(random);
                comp++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
System.out.println(random);
```

This implementation is trying to print the random number generator, not the numbers themselves. There is a much easier solution, using the built-in [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)):

```
List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>(students);
for (int number = 0; number < students; number++)
    positions.add(number);

Collections.shuffle(positions);

for (Integer number : positions)
    System.out.println(number);
```